# Convert Array presented as String

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, matrix, readfile

I have a text-file with following data:

```
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 3, 2]
```

When i read the file with `fs.read` i got Strings like this:

```
'[2,3,4]'
'[1,3,4]'
```

And because of that the length of my matrix `mat` is wrong.

Code:

```
var mat = [];

var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./data/outfilename', function(err, data) {

  if (err) throw err;
  var array = data.toString().split(/\r?\n/);



  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    if (array[i].length > 0) {
      mat.push(array[i]);
    }
  }

  console.log(mat.length);
  console.log(mat[0].length);



});
```

How i convert the read-line to an array with numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string as JSON:

```js
// dummy data
var array = ['[2,3,4]', '[18,4,3]'];

var mat = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  mat.push(JSON.parse(array[i]));
}

console.log(mat);
```

Or using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
// dummy data
var array = ['[2,3,4]', '[18,4,3]'];

var mat = array.map(JSON.parse);

console.log(mat);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JSON.parse` to convert the strings in the array to array of numbers:

```js
var array = ['[2,3,4]', '[1,3,4]'];

mat =  array.map(s => JSON.parse(s));

console.log(mat);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var matrix = array.map(JSON.parse)
```

will transform your array into the matrix that you want.

The strings at each line are JSON representations of array of numbers, so when you apply JSON.parse on each line you have the corresponding array.